# Loop Issue: Extracting mean temps for each layer of RasterStack (NetCDF File)

Tags: raster, r, loop, rasterstack, rasterbrick

I am running into a little bit of a problem with a RasterStack loop. I am trying to extract the mean temperature for each county in North Carolina for each hour over the last 10 years. I am able to run some simple code and get this for each layer with relative ease but as I am trying to loop this process to get the mean for every timestamp in the Raster Stack/Brick, I am not having much luck.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(ncdf4)
librarcy(exactextractr)

# Brick the NC File 
r<-stack("ERA_Temps.nc") 

output <- for (i in 1:length(r)) {
                    
              wgsraster <- r[[i]]
                    
              year <- str_sub(names(wgsraster), 2, 5)
              month <- str_sub(names(wgsraster), 7, 8)
              day <- str_sub(names(wgsraster), 10, 11)
              hour <- str_sub(names(wgsraster), 13, 14)
                    
              NC_Counties <- cbind(shp, exact_extract(wgsraster, shp, c('mean')))
                    
              output_df <- data.frame(County.Name = NC_Counties$NAME, GEOID = NC_Counties$GEOID, temp_mean = NC_Counties$mean, year, month, day, hour)
                    return(output_df)
                  }

Output <- output_df
```

Examples and More Info:

```
 r
    class      : RasterStack 
    dimensions : 81, 81, 6561, 72  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
    resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
    extent     : -90.125, -69.875, 24.875, 45.125  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
    names      : X2018.09.14.00.00.00, X2018.09.14.01.00.00, X2018.09.14.02.00.00, X2018.09.14.03.00.00, X2018.09.14.04.00.00, X2018.09.14.05.00.00, X2018.09.14.06.00.00, X2018.09.14.07.00.00, X2018.09.14.08.00.00, X2018.09.14.09.00.00, X2018.09.14.10.00.00, X2018.09.14.11.00.00, X2018.09.14.12.00.00, X2018.09.14.13.00.00, X2018.09.14.14.00.00, ...
```

I can fairly easily get what I need for an individual layer:

```
wgsraster <- r[[5]]
                
year <- str_sub(names(wgsraster), 2, 5)
month <- str_sub(names(wgsraster), 7, 8)
day <- str_sub(names(wgsraster), 10, 11)
hour <- str_sub(names(wgsraster), 13, 14)
                
NC_Counties <- cbind(shp, exact_extract(wgsraster, shp, c('mean')))
                
output_df <- data.frame(County.Name = NC_Counties$NAME, GEOID = NC_Counties$GEOID, temp_mean = NC_Counties$exact_extract.wgsraster..shp..c..mean...,
                                        year, month, day, hour)

output_df
     County.Name GEOID temp_mean year month day hour
1         Saluda 45081  298.3141 2018    09  14   11
2   Williamsburg 45089  300.2301 2018    09  14   11
3     Dorchester 45035  299.3716 2018    09  14   11
4       Berkeley 45015  299.7389 2018    09  14   11
5      Greenwood 45047  298.5175 2018    09  14   11
```

But when I try and run the loop mentioned above, it either fails and gives no output or gives the following error:

> Error in .local(x, i, j, ...) : you must provide an index

Answer (score 0):

`for` and `return` don't work like you think they do in a `for` loop:

```
output <- for (i in 1:length(r)) {
                    
      wgsraster <- r[[i]]

      [code]   

      output_df <- data.frame([stuff])
      return(output_df)
}
```

First, there's no point assigning the value of `for` to anything:

```
> z = for(i in 1:10){return(i)}
> z
NULL
```

its always `NULL`.

Secondly, `return` quits the `for` loop:

```
> z = for(i in 1:10){message(i);return(i)}
1
```

here only `1` is printed, and the return is still `NULL`. Without `return`:

```
> z = for(i in 1:10){message(i)}
1
2
3
[up to 10]
```

What you either want to do is use something like `lapply` and return a list, or construct a list by extending it within the for loop:

```
> times2 = lapply(1:3, function(x){c(x,x*2)})
> times2
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 4

[[3]]
[1] 3 6

> times3 = list()
> for(i in 1:3){times3[[i]] = c(i,i*3)}
> times3
[[1]]
[1] 1 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 6

[[3]]
[1] 3 9
```

It might also be a good practice to put the code you have currently in the loop into a *function*, so you can test that and then easily put it in an `lapply` loop.